# Multiplication of two Riemann-integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, fake-proofs

Let's assume that $f:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ are both Riemann-integrable functions. Then we know that multiplying both functions,i.e. $fg= f(x)g(x)$, is also a Riemann-integrable function. However, it is not true that
$$\int_1^2f(x)g(x)dx = \int_1^2f(x)dx \int_1^2g(x)dx$$

We can take for example $1=x\frac{1}{x}$ and see:
$$1=\int_1^21dx = \int_1^2 x\frac{1}{x}dx\neq\int_1^2xdx \int_1^2\frac{1}{x} dx =1.5 \ln(2)$$

---

If I try to calculate the Riemann-integral via Darboux sums and take an arbitrary partition $P$ of $[1,2]$, then on each subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ of $P$ I get:

$$
1=\inf\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(f)\inf\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(g)\leq \inf\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(fg)\leq \sup\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(f)\sup\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(g)=1,
$$
because $f$ is the inverse of $g$.

Refining the partition yields the integral and would lead to the **false** conclusion that
$$
1=\int_1^2 x\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_1^2xdx \int_1^2\frac{1}{x} dx=1
$$
Where is my mistake?

Comment: how do you get the product of inf and product of sups are $1$? They should be $t_{i-1}\cdot\frac{1}{t_i}$ and $t_{i}\cdot \frac{1}{t_{i-1}}$ respectively.

Comment: $\inf fg$ is not necessarily $(\inf f)(\inf g$\,.

Comment: Your mistake is that $1 \neq \inf\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(f)\inf\limits_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(g)$, and the same $\neq$ for the supremes. You can search online the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals to see a valid proof of the inequality between your expressions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, oops I see, this was a stupid mistake I did  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, as some users have already pointed out, is that you know that $1=\inf_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}(fg)$ (since $fg$ is constantly 1), but not (as you claim) that $1$ is equal to the product of the infima.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I see that we have $\inf(f)=t_{i-1}$ and $\inf(g)=\frac{1}{t_i}$ which implies $\inf(f)\inf(g)<1$, since $t_{i-1}<t_i$. How is it possible that the value of the integral is $$\int_1^2f(x)dx\int_1^2\frac{1}{x}dx= 1.5\ln(2)>1$$ while the $\inf(f)\inf(g)<1$ on each subinterval of the partitition? If I refine the partitition I don't see how it will push it above $1$?

Comment: In order to calculate the product of the integrals, you first have to calculate one integral, then the other, and then their product. The way to approximate this via lower Darboux sums is something like $L(f,P)L(g,P)$, which is not equal to $\sum_{I\in P} (\operatorname{inf}(f)\operatorname{inf}(g)\mu(I))$ (as it seems that you claim), but rather $(\sum_{I\in P} (\operatorname{inf}(f)\mu(I))(\sum_{I\in P} (\operatorname{inf}(g)\mu(I))$.

Comment: Ahh ok, that's it. Instead of multiplying $L(f,P)$ and $L(g,P)$ (both are finite sums for a given partitition $P$), I "merged" them incorrectly.